# how to get the whole list object variables and arrays without need to get from object child id gundb?

Tags: gun, gundb

I just notice that object child of object has id but not that I wanted that when I try to get the object variable. I wanted what store in object of object but I found id only?

For example I used scene manage the objects to save and load for easy access.

{
 x:0,
 y:0,
 z:0,
 prarms:{height:0,width:0}
}

result from save is when I check the data I found it different.

{
 x:0,
 y:0,
 z:0,
 prarms:#randomids
}

I used set and put if the objects matches using the uuid. Need a bit of help on how it get it working. Wanted to get the whole object data but not the gundb object ids.

---

Manage to get partly working code for set and get data object to work partly. Here simple version how to set.

```
//console.log("saving object data????");
        this.check_gunsceneobj(obj['uuid'],(bfind,id)=>{
            //console.log("....CALLS");
            var gscene = this.gun.get('scene');
            //check child keys var is object to put var
            function gunObjectAssign(_gun, _obj){
                for(var i in _obj){
                    if(typeof _obj[i] == 'object'){
                        console.log(i);
                        //pathing for object child of object
                        _gun.path(i).put(_obj[i]);
                        gunObjectAssign(_gun.path(i),_obj[i]);
                    }
                }
            }
            if(bfind){
                console.log("set object scene[update]");
                if(id !=null){
                    console.log(id);
                    gscene.path(id).put(obj);
                    gunObjectAssign(gscene.path(id),obj);
                }
            }else{
                console.log("save object scene[insert]");
                //console.log(obj);
                gscene.set(obj);
            }
            console.log("object save?");
        });
```

here the get objects.

```
function gunObjDataAssign(self,data){
                    for(var i in data){
                        if(typeof data[i] === 'object'){
                            if(data[i] !=null){
                                var id = data[i]['#'];
                                data[i] = {}; //clear id hash
                                self.get(id).val((objdata)=>{
                                    delete objdata._;
                                    data[i] = objdata;
                                    gunObjDataAssign(self,objdata);
                                });
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }

                Gun.chain.valueobj = function (cb, opt) {
                  return this.val(function (val, field) {
                      if(val !=null){
                          delete val._;
                      }
                      gunObjDataAssign(this,val);
                      cb.call(this, val, field);
                  }, opt);
                };

                Gun.chain.liveobj = function (cb, opt) {
                  return this.on(function (val, field) {
                    delete val._;
                    gunObjDataAssign(this,val);
                    cb.call(this, val, field);
                  }, opt);
                };

                Gun.chain.eachobj = function () {
                  var each = this.map();
                  return this.valueobj.apply(each, arguments);
                };
```

Have not fully tested. But it worked party not try detect any update once push to the scene objects.

Used Sample Code from snippets.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly... you probably want to use this plugin:

https://github.com/gundb/synchronous

```
gun.get('player').sync({}, {}, function(player){
  // player updated!
  console.log("Full object, not just pointers:", player);
})
```

There is also https://github.com/gundb/onward which gives you the diff and path on the document.

Does this help? Let me know and I'll revise the answer as necessary.